# polymer-slider immedateValue change events

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer

I've ported my old polymer code that used a slider input field to a paper-slider. I can see that there is an immediateValue attribute but can't find a corresponding event. i.e. I want to get a continuous set of change events as the user drags the slider so I can update my diagram continuously.

How do I do that with paper-slider?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I didn't need to listen to the event, but just bind to both values like

```
  <paper-slider id="slider" editable min="0" max="100" step="0.1"
    value="{{sliderValue | asPercent}}"
    immediateValue="{{sliderValue | asPercent}}">
  </paper-slider>
```